# Query not returning in order

Tags: php, mysql

If you require any additional information for me to help you assist me please let me know. The project requires to be password protected, though.

I am utterly baffled at the moment because I have a functioning piece of code in this section of an uncompleted project, or so I thought. I am looking for any and all advice that will help solve this problem.

I am not getting a 'sane' result, I am doing the same thing twice and getting different results. Both pieces of code return ALL of the answers to the SAME question successfully, but one of them is displaying them in order 17, 18, 19, 16 within the exact block of code, while the second displays 16, 17, 18, 19 in proper order.

In the second piece of code as well, which is part of a more detailed view of a given question and all answers associated with it (just a more detailed view of the first code), the edit functions will edit the correct code, but the delete check boxes fail and delete the wrong item. This pattern does NOT coincide with the visual ordering of the malfunctioning code, either, and appears quite random. This may be the same or a different problem, and I am looking into this.

As follows with two sections of code, one of the sections is displaying rows of the data of all of the answers to a question:

```
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM ST_Answers
    WHERE referencingQuestionID = '$permIDNum'
    ORDER BY 'permanentAnsNumber'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    $ret = "";
    $letter = "a";

    $ret .= "<div class='lq answerListItem'>";
    $ret .= "<span class='lqh2 answerNumber'> &nbsp; </span>";
    $ret .= "<span class='lqh2 answerTextBody'>Answer Text Body</span>";
    $ret .= "<span class='lqh2 answerSummaryText'>Answer Summary Text</span>";
    $ret .= "<span class='lqh2 answerNextQuestion'>Next Q#</span>";
    $ret .= "<span class='lqh2 correct'>Correct?</span>";
    $ret .= "</div>";


    $i = 0;
    $n = mysql_numrows($result2);
    while( $i < $n ){
            $permAID = mysql_result($result2,$i,"permanentAnsNumber");
        $aText = mysql_result($result2,$i,"answerTextBody");
        $aSummary = mysql_result($result2,$i,"answerSummaryText");
        $nextQID = mysql_result($result2,$i,"nextQuestionID");
        $correctA = mysql_result($result2,$i,"correctAnswer");

        $ret .= "<div class='lq answerListItem'>";
        if($letter != "a") { $ret .= "<br/>"; }
        $ret .= "<span class='lq answerNumber'> &nbsp; </span>";
            $ret .= "<span class='lq answerTextBody'>" . $letter . ") $aText </span>";
        $ret .= "<span class='lq answerSummaryText'>" . $aSummary . "</span>";
        $ret .= "<span class='lq answerNextQuestion'>" . $nextQID . "</span>";
        $ret .= "<span class='lq correct'>" . $correctA . "</span>";
        $letter++;
        $ret .= "</div>";
        $i++;
    }
```

This second piece of code, is displaying the same data but a bit more using the SAME query, but instead of displaying items out of order, it displays them properly in the correct order, yet the code is almost exactly the same!

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM ST_Answers
    WHERE referencingQuestionID='$permID' 
    ORDER BY 'permanentAnsNumber'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$ret .= "<div id='answerContainer'><h3>Associated Answers: </h3>";

$i = 0;
$n = mysql_numrows($result2);
// NOTE: This is displaying everything in correct order
// TODO: Reference this
while( $i < $n ){
        $permAID = mysql_result($result2,$i,"permanentAnsNumber");
    $aText = mysql_result($result2,$i,"answerTextBody");
    $aSummary = mysql_result($result2,$i,"answerSummaryText");
    $nextQID = mysql_result($result2,$i,"nextQuestionID");
    $correctA = mysql_result($result2,$i,"correctAnswer");

    $ret .= "<div class='answerRow'>";
        $ret .= "<span class='perAID'>" . "<h5>Answer ID(Warning do not change):<textarea rows='1' cols='4' name='ids[]'>" . $permAID . "</textarea></span></h5>";
        $ret .= "<span class='aText'>" . "Answer Text: <br /><textarea name='aTxt[]' rows='5' cols='40'>" . $aText . "</textarea></span><br />";
        $ret .= "<span class='aSummary'>" . "Answer Summary: <br /><textarea name='aSum[]' rows='5' cols='40'>" . $aSummary . "</textarea></span><br />";
        $ret .= "<span class='nextQID'>Question this leads to: <textarea name='nxtQID[]' rows='1' cols='4'>" . $nextQID . "</textarea></span><br />";
        $ret .= "<span class='correctA'>" . "Answer point value: <textarea name='ansCorrect[]' rows='1' cols='2'>" . $correctA . "</textarea></span><br />";
        $ret .= "<span class='del'><h6>Delete? <input type='checkbox' name='delete[]'></h6></span><br />";
    $ret .= "</div><br />";

    $i++;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on where to even begin with this? I'm entirely stumped.

Comment: `$permIDNum` in first query `$permID` in second?

Comment: They are actually the same value, just different names. They were in separate parts of the code, I am going to convert it so they are the same shortly.

Comment: Backticks (`) are not the same as inverted commas (')

Comment: argh, `mysql_result()`... use `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) { $permAID = $row['permanentAnsNumber']; ... }`. This will improve performance, and also is the correct way (and when you transition to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`, then it will be the only way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you use quotes around a column name. Introducing that way a constant literal string to `ORDER BY` you effectively eliminate the ordering of the resultset.

Change

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM ST_Answers WHERE referencingQuestionID = '$permIDNum' 
           ORDER BY 'permanentAnsNumber'";
                    ^                  ^
```

to

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM ST_Answers WHERE referencingQuestionID = '$permIDNum' 
           ORDER BY permanentAnsNumber";
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3045b/2)** demo.

On a side note: learn and use  [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). Mysql_* extension is deprecated.

Comment: It's not that, the syntax allows for either method. I've tried this in addition just in case, and it was not that. Additionally I know about them being deprecated, and I prefer mysqli just there is far too much of this code that in the other format, and I will be converting it all at once. There should not be a functional difference, unless you have a reference for such.

Comment: _"the syntax allows for either method"_ - yes, but the effects are completely different.

Comment: How are the effects different? Could you please explain? I always put things in quotes, and deleted the quotes earlier during my testing to see if that caused a difference and forgot to replace them.

Comment: @user2496400 **It's exactly that**. You are probably confused about using ticks and quotes. Former allows you to use special characters and reserved words as object names, the latter defines string literals. See updated answer for an explanation and sqlfiddle that shows you the difference.

Comment: I actually just fixed the problem somehow and I don't exactly get how I did it. I moved the same code from within a function, to being cut and pasted within the code and disabled the old function. For some reason all of a sudden the display order is correct. What could be happening? I only sent an integer to the function. When within a function, the same code is going nuts and when outside of a function, it doesn't. It works with one quoted, both quoted, or neither quoted so it's not exactly that.

Comment: @user2496400 The fact that you got proper ordering before while using quotes around column names is purely coincidental.

Comment: Actually you are correct about the coincidental part. I just realized not only was it what you were saying after all, it was because a function higher up was quoted too on the order by part, and when both are fixed, it works. Thank you, I wouldn't have ever discovered this on my own. Do you know why it would work sometimes for me and other times it would not?

Answer (score 0):

I advice you change your style, try to use this

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM ST_Answers WHERE referencingQuestionID='$permID' ORDER BY permanentAnsNumber";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$ret .= "<div id='answerContainer'><h3>Associated Answers: </h3>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

    $ret .= "<div class='answerRow'>";
        $ret .= "<span class='perAID'>" . "<h5>Answer ID(Warning do not change):<textarea rows='1' cols='4' name='ids[]'>" . $row["permanentAnsNumber"] . "</textarea></span></h5>";
        $ret .= "<span class='aText'>" . "Answer Text: <br /><textarea name='aTxt[]' rows='5' cols='40'>" . $row["answerTextBody"] . "</textarea></span><br />";
        $ret .= "<span class='aSummary'>" . "Answer Summary: <br /><textarea name='aSum[]' rows='5' cols='40'>" . $row["answerSummaryText"] . "</textarea></span><br />";
        $ret .= "<span class='nextQID'>Question this leads to: <textarea name='nxtQID[]' rows='1' cols='4'>" . $row["nextQuestionID"] . "</textarea></span><br />";
        $ret .= "<span class='correctA'>" . "Answer point value: <textarea name='ansCorrect[]' rows='1' cols='2'>" . $row["correctAnswer"] . "</textarea></span><br />";
        $ret .= "<span class='del'><h6>Delete? <input type='checkbox' name='delete[]'></h6></span><br />";
    $ret .= "</div><br />";

}
```

Comment: This worked for the same reason that peterm originally stated, I was wrong to argue with him :)

Comment: You right, i am talking only about style differences ;)
using `mysql_fetch_assoc` is comfortable

Answer (score 0):

Use string and variable concatenation methods while trying to use php variables inside your query or string. Quotes are not required after 'ORDERBY'. take care that too.. This changes may help you here.

change the query :

> $query2 = "SELECT * FROM ST_Answers WHERE referencingQuestionID =
>   '".$permIDNum."' ORDER BY permanentAnsNumber";

Answer (score 0):

As Peterm stated, you can't have quotes in this code around the 'ORDER BY' specifier. Once fixed in this piece of code as well as a parent piece of code higher up, everything displays correctly.